# Dealing with symbol resolution properly in macros

Tags: clojure

Say I want to make a Clojure macro that does the following:

```
If x is a list calling the function "bar"
  return :foobar
else
  return x as a string
```

However, `bar` is not defined; rather, it is only used internally in the macro, like so:

```
(foo (bar))
:foobar

(foo 1)
"1"
```

One could do something like this:

```
(defmacro foo [x] 
  (if (and (coll? x) (= (first x) 'bar)) 
      :foobar 
      (str x)))
```

This works great for the `(bar)` case, as well as for literals. However, symbols do not work as intended, giving the symbol name instead of its associated value:

```
user=> (def y 2)
#'user/y
user=> (foo y)
"y"
```

One could call the `eval` function on `x` before passing it to `str`, but this causes problem when using the function in `let`:

```
user=> (let [a 3 b (foo a)] b)
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't eval locals (NO_SOURCE_FILE:89)
```

Presumably, the problem has to do with symbol resolution, so maybe we try to work something out with syntax-quote:

```
(defmacro foo [x] 
  `(if (and (coll? '~x) (= (first '~x) '~'bar)) 
    :foobar 
    (str ~x)))
```

Now, the problem is with `(foo (bar))`, as this expands the else clause to `(clojure.core/str (bar))`, which throws an exception, as `bar` is not defined. I then tried doing some shenanigans with `eval`:

```
(defmacro foo [x] 
  `(if (and (coll? '~x) (= (first '~x) '~'bar)) 
    :foobar 
    (eval '(str ~x))))
```

But this doesn't work with `let` bindings again:

```
user=> (let [a 1 b (foo a)] b)
java.lang.Exception: Unable to resolve symbol: a in this context (NO_SOURCE_FILE:153)
```

So I'm really at a loss here. It seems as though fixing one problem breaks another. Is there a better, simpler way of making this macro such that it works in the following cases:

- In `let` bindings
- With `(bar)`
- With symbols

P.S. If anybody is curious as to *why* I want to do this, I'm working on a DSL for Yahoo's YQL service and I want to be able to do things like `(select (table :t) ...)`, but I need to be able to pass in symbols, as well as literals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this should work.

```
(defmacro foo [x]
  (if (and (coll? x) (= (first x) 'bar))
    :foobar
    `(str ~x)))
```

Comment: I guess I didn't consider syntax-quoting only part of the expression, but that seems to do it. Thanks!